# Raspberry Pi + Tensorflow Camera Demo = Slow

Tags: tensorflow

Following tutorial of [Raspberry Pi camera demo](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/pi_examples):

1) I first compiled Tensorflow 0.11 with optimization flags on Raspberry Pi Model 3 with Raspbian 8 ([Makefile](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/makefile))

2) then I compiled `camera` code

3) and last I run the demo.

Demo works, but there is a ~12 seconds delay between real scene framed with camera and acquisition of the frame. Then it takes ~3/4 seconds to evaluate frames.

It's really slow in capturing frames. It's an issue related to RPi specs?

**UPDATE:**

I'm using the official Raspberry Pi camera module v2. Moreover, I run `camera` demo with default parameters.

Comment: Facing a similar problem. I have a script that captures an image, decides what action it should take, and executes said action. The decision is, however, being taken based on frames from > 5 seconds before, despite the frame rate being around ~0,5 FPS.